# ./learncoind not connecting to DigitalOcean Droplet

Tags: litecoin, daemon, learning

I'm on video 5 of the [Learncoin youtube series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ENaTmbh8Xuw&nohtml5=False) and I am getting an error when I try to run `./learncoind`

```
2016-04-07 03:40:40 connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
2016-04-07 03:40:40 trying connection MY-DROPLET-IP:9333
```

I have my SSH key setup for the droplet and the keys live in my ~/.ssh/id_rsa folder. I can access my droplet from the CLI using ssh root@MY-DROPLET-IP and then entering my SSH key password and my root password.

I don't really understand why ./learncoind isn't connecting.

Comment: If you run `netstat -antlp | grep LIST` on your droplet, is anything listening on port 9333?